# Developers Story bug report: cannot get past second screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

This is more of a bug report.  I'm trying to fill in the second screen of the Developer Story, but after clicking "Done", I'm moving back to the top of the page and presented with the error message "All fields are required", even though all fields have values:

[image: Second screen with error messages]

It could be that the error is the "tag field" for the technologies being used: the error message states "two required", but I am uncertain as to whether that means "at least two are required", or "exactly two are required".  Trying with either 2 or 4 produces the same outcome.

**OS:** macOS 10.14

**Browser:** Vivaldi

Answer (score 3):

While it's not very clear from the on-page messaging, the actual issue is that you don't have enough characters in the "What are your responsibilities?" section. It requires 75 characters and your about 20 short of that.

Please try filling in a bit more detail into the "What are your responsibilities?" field and retry saving.  If that doesn't work, please comment here.

Meanwhile, I'll work on making the validation error more obvious on the page.

---

Update: validation on the page was basically broken. I've fixed that so it's clear what fields are failing validation and what you need to change.

Comment: Yes it works as expected. Thanks a lot for the fix.