# When filling Developer Story, unable to submit because "Two required", although I have filled more than 2 technologies

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

I'm new on Stack Overflow and I'm trying to fill my Developer Story, but every time I click Done button I see:

[image]

and form says "All fields are required".
I tried to put only 2 technologies but I got same result. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly what part are you trying to fill?

Comment: Hi, preferred technologies part. I putted 5 tags but I got always the same error "Two required". Thanks for the answer!

Comment: So you are talking about the field **Tech you want to work with** and the button you are clicking is **Save**?

Comment: I mean field "Which technologies are you using there?" and the button I'm clicking is "Done"

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot find that field. Exactly what steps are you going through to reproduce this error?

Comment: When you edit yuor Stack Overflow profile, you have 4 buttons on top: "Profile", "Activity", "Developer Story" and "Edit profile and settings". If you click on Developer Story, you have to fill a form with: "Name", "Current location", "Preferred technologies" and "Job search status". I can't complete this form because, all the times I click on Done button I got an error "All fields are required". Seems that I haven't correctly filled the field "Preferred technologies" because close to him I see the error "Two required".

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. It seems you had that in the question already, but it wasn't properly formatted, so it wasn't rendering. Fixed now. I think this may be the same bug as reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393079/developers-story-bug-report-cannot-get-pass-second-screen). That was marked as "planned to fix" by a SO Jobs developer, but I don't know what's taking so long on that fix. It seems like a pretty serious bug. Are you also using Vivaldi?

Comment: Yes it is the same bug! I'm using Chrome. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: confirmed this is a bug. Validation in general is broken on that page. A fix is in the deployment pipe.  For what it's worth, the "Two required" was a misdirection.  There's something else on the page that's not meeting validation, but the page isn't telling you.  Check that your "what are your responsibilities" section has at least 75 characters in it -- that seems to be the most common issue.

Comment: @CodyGray seems that this bug is solved. Today I tried and I was able to fill my Developer Story.

Comment: Yes, it was fixed by the Jobs developer John W. Wright, as he commented here and in [an answer to the question I marked this as a duplicate of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399378/).